# Cannot start VirtualBox VM with PCI device attached

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, pci

- VirtualBox version: 6.0.4
- Extension pack version: 6.0.4
- Host OS: Windows 10

I have installed VirtualBox extension pack:

[image]

and attached PCI device (Nvidia GPU) to my virtual machine w/ VBoxManage tool:

[image]

And when I'm trying to start VM, this error pops up:

[image]

I have changed VM's chipset to ICH9 and if PCI is detached, VM starts just fine. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: @music2myear Sorry, fixed it.

Comment: You must be running Linux as the host OS: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E97728_01/F12469/html/pcipassthrough.html